# Adding to the dir() of instance

Tags: python

I have a class (named "A") with some instance variables. I want to add the dir() of this variables to the dir() of instances of class A.

For example:

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
class X(object):
    def f_x(self):
        pass
class Y(object):
    def f_y(self):
        pass

x = X(); y = Y()
a = A(x,y)
```

I want f_x and f_y to appear in

```
dir(a)
```

Is there a better way, or a more 'correct' one, than just iterating X.**dict** and Y.**dict** and for each element, use something like:

```
setattr(A, str(element), element)
```

Thanks.

Comment: What do you __really__ want to do? The thing you wrote doesn't make much sense

Comment: @Franklin: First, thank you. To simplify my actual example, classes X and Y both are sort of 'given' to me, and they both implement some functionality that I want to encapsulate.
Therefore I'm not sure that inheritance is right in my actual example.
I just want the users of my class (class A) to be able to see all the functions from both X and Y without knowing that I hold x and y as instance variables.

Comment: Can users of the class actually call those functions without knowing about the instance variables? If so, how? If not, are you **really** asking how to make **that** possible?

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you simply inherit from both classes?

```
class B(A, X):
    pass

a = B()
dir(a)
```

Answer (score 2):

`A` should really be a subclass of `X` and `Y` in this case. (Just be sure to read [Michele Simionato's article on `super` and diamond inheritence](http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=281127) before you get too deep into it.)

```
class X(object):
    def f_x(self):
        pass

class Y(object):
    def f_y(self):
        pass

class A(X, Y):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs): # splats optional
        # do what you need to here

dir(A(X(),Y())) # Ah! Lisp!
```

However, if you *really* need things to be magic, then just override `__getattr__` for `X` to look in `self.x` and `self.y` before throwing an error.  But seriously, don't do this.

Comment: What are the .x and .y members of A doing for you here?

Comment: @Russell - they give me access to an instance of the class `X` and an instance of the class `Y` that my subclass `A` needs to do something important.  (I'm assuming that `A` *acts* as an `X` or a `Y` ... if it needs to **act on** its own `self.x` and `self.y` instances then we would need to override `f_x` and `f_y` in `A`. Alternately, if it is supposed to be an `X` and a `Y` then it probably doesn't need the instances of `x` and `y`.)

Comment: It seems to me like inheriting from `X` and `Y` is the very essence of "supposed to be an `X` and a `Y`". If `self.f_x()` is supposed to do the same as `self.x.f_x()`, the x member is redundant, and if it doesn't mean the same, it's error prone.

Comment: @Russel -- good point.  I can think of a few scenarios where something might *be a kind of* and also *have one of that kind*, but I cannot think of any **good** ones right now - so I have updated my code example.  Thanks!